# How to create step by step annotated programming tutorial  in LaTeX?

Tags: beamer, tutorials, literate-programming, pause

(question inspired by [How to create a crossword puzzle in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44775/how-to-create-a-crossword-puzzle-in-latex) and provided solutions)

How to make in most comfortable way in LaTeX (I use pdfLaTeX, but I am open for LuaTeX solutions) annotated, step by step, programming tutorials?
Preferably from annotated sourcecode? Or in other way, by less effort than typing each slide by slide.

I means questions and answers tutorial in form of presentation (I don't know if `beamer` is the only solution for presentations, but I've heard it's popular one).

Here is an example how such presentation would look like:

```
*-------------------------------------------*
|      How to implement Main function?      |
|                                           |
|                                           |
| (1)?                                      |
|                                           |
|                                           |
|                                           |
|                                           |
|    (2)?                                   |
| (1)                                       |
|                                           |
| (1) ... ?                                 |
| (2) ... ?                                 |
*-------------------------------------------*

*-------------------------------------------*
|              Main function                |
|                                           |
|                                           |
| int main(){ (1)                           |
|                                           |
|                                           |
|                                           |
|                                           |
|    return 0; (2)                          |
| } (1)                                     |
|                                           |
| (1) ...                                   |
| (2) ...                                   |
*-------------------------------------------*

*-------------------------------------------*
|        How to perform Computation?        |
|                                           |
|                                           |
| int main(){                               |
|    (3)?                                   |
|                                           |
|    (4)?                                   |
|                                           |
|    return 0;                              |
| }                                         |
|                                           |
| (3) ...?                                  |
| (4) ...?                                  |
*-------------------------------------------*

*-------------------------------------------*
|              Computation                  |
|                                           |
|                                           |
| int main(){                               |
|    long a,b,c; (3)                        |
|                                           |
|    c = a * b; (4)                         |
|                                           |
|    return 0;                              |
| }                                         |
|                                           |
| (3) ...                                   |
| (4) ...                                   |
*-------------------------------------------*

*-------------------------------------------*
|            Input & Output  ?              |
|                                           |
| (5) ?                                     |
| int main(){                               |
|    long a,b,c;                            |
|    (6) ?                                  |
|    c = a * b;                             |
|    (6) ?                                  |
|    return 0;                              |
| }                                         |
|                                           |
| (5) ...?                                  |
| (6) ...?                                  |
*-------------------------------------------*

*-------------------------------------------*
|            Input & Output                 |
|                                           |
| #include <cstdio> (5)                     |
| int main(){                               |
|    long a,b,c;                            |
|    scanf("%ld%ld", &a, &b); (6)           |
|    c = a * b;                             |
|    printf("%ld\n", c); (6)                |
|    return 0;                              |
| }                                         |
|                                           |
| (5) ...                                   |
| (6) ...                                   |
*-------------------------------------------*
```

Comment: Although not exactly clear what you ask, I think you can do it with itemize environment with `\pause`. Also, you might like [this question and its answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37869/beamer-animations-how-to-simulate-terminal-input-and-output).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

An interactive version with `beamer` may be constructed along the following lines:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]%
\begin{semiverbatim}
\frametitle{Input \&\ Output}
\#include <cstdio>
\only<1>{(1)?}\only<2->{int main() \{}
   \only<3>{(3)?}\only<4->{long a,b,c;}
   \only<4>{(4)?}\only<5->{std::scanf("\%ld\%ld", \&a, \&b);}
   \only<5>{(5)?}\only<6->{c = a * b;}
   \only<6>{(6)?}\only<7->{std::printf("\%ld\textbackslash n", c);}
   \only<2>{(2)?}\only<3->{return 0;}
 \}
\end{semiverbatim}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great ! It will save a lot of my time life :).

Comment: Very nice :). If you use such techniques for teaching purposes, I've found tool (however it's not TeX, but web interactive) to make similar visualisations automatically , nice to give a try (:)) : [Online Python Tutor](http://people.csail.mit.edu/pgbovine/python/) and [related web article](http://www.stanford.edu/~pgbovine/online-python-tutor.htm)

Comment: @Andrey-Vihrov Example uses `cstdio` in `C++` because it's tailored to pitfalls of programming contests like http://www.spoj.pl/ - `iostream` can be to slow for such contests. On many contests `return 0` is requirement to get solution accepted.

Comment: @GrzegorzWierzowiecki: My comment was not very polite :-S The speed of iostreams varies per platform (in my tests I found that iostreams is even faster on reading `int`s with GCC 4.4 on 64-bit Linux; but slower on MSVC) and isn't important even in programming contests, unless you are inputting a very large set of data. In my opinion, this isn't enough to sacrifice the simplicity and type safety of iostreams in examples. Now, in C++, reaching the closing brace `}` of `main()` is _equivalent_ to writing `return 0;` at the end. So you don't need it after all. That's all I have to say. Cheers!

Comment: I know all what you've wrote. However, some contests use specific versions of compilers and standard libraries, tailored to contests needs and it happens a lot, that solutions using iostreams a slower. That same applies to `return 0`. On the other hand - there are application where you are not in such comfort of using modern compiler -> like specific embedded micro-controlers. To sup it up: I appreciate your corrections and understand motivations, while in same time, just clarity that there are applications where rules are slightly different. All best :).