# Beamer: How to do src highlighting when src is split with \only<> command?

Tags: beamer, listings, highlighting, sourcecode

Thanks to [Marc van Dongen](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/10274/marc-van-dongen) there is a template of a "step by step" programming tutorial (with a sample layout in his question): [How to create step by step annotated programming tutorial  in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44959/how-to-create-step-by-step-annotated-programming-tutorial-in-latex) .

I wonder if it is possible to achieve similar functionality with source highlighting ?

Simply changing environment from `semiverbatim` to `lstlisting` , does not work (as is easy to guess).

```
%Generate with : `pdflatex filename`
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
    language=C++,
    basicstyle=\small,
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]%
%\begin{semiverbatim}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=C++,caption={C++ as C++ TexTests},label=cppascpptextests]
\only<1-2>{\frametitle{General program structure}}
\only<3>{\frametitle{Variables}}
\only<4>{\frametitle{Reading numbers from standard input}}
\only<5>{\frametitle{Printing results on standard output}}
\only<6>{\frametitle{Assigning results of computation}}
\only<7>{\frametitle{Working example :)}}
\only<8>{\frametitle{Enjoy programming :)}}
\only<4>{(4)How to include needed header file?}\only<5->{\#include <cstdio>}
\only<1>{(1) How to construct main function ?}\only<2->{int main() \{}
   \only<3>{(3) How to declare variables?}\only<4->{long a,b,c;}
   \only<4>{(4) How to read data?}\only<5->{scanf("\%ld\%ld", \&a, \&b);}
   \only<6>{(6) How to compute result?}\only<7->{c = a * b;}
   \only<5>{(5) How to print result?}\only<6->{printf("\%ld\textbackslash n", c);}
   \only<2>{(2) How to exit program correctly?}\only<3->{return 0;}
\only<2->{\}}
\end{lstlisting}
%\end{semiverbatim}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Not yet the time for a real answer: The general advice here is to use the `escapechar=` option in your listing settings to escape to LaTeX inside the listing. This can be used to bring in the `\only` commands. The problem is, though, that the stuff inside the LaTeX code does not get syntax highlighting. A more elegant way is to use `moredelims=` to hide this stuff in a listings style, take http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/18266/3751 for an inspiration.

Comment: (Continued...) The tricky part in your case is that you do not only want lines of your listing to appear and disappear, but want the comments to be replaced. I might be a lot easier if the comments could remain (e.g., by turning them to  EOL-Comments, like `long a,b,c;        // (3) How to declare variables?`) with the comment being allowed to stay after slide 3.

Comment: @Daniel - Questions can be as comments, and other modifications are welcome. Above example is idea, about general shape. What about possible solutions - the idea that come to my mind is to get whole source code listed, and then to hide lines and program fragments by painting on them with rectangles of color of background. However, I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: Please don't get me wrong but you are only a little far from including all into seperate frames and using the power of `lstlistings` independently.

Comment: Grzegorz: If the given answer has solved your problem, please consider accepting it. If not, you might want to update your MWE to show the particular deficiencies, so the community could improve the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is a possible solution approach for combining `beamer` overlays with `lstlisting`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{beramono}
\usepackage{pgf,pgffor}
\lstset{
    language=C++,
    basicstyle=\small,
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
}

\lstdefinestyle{highlight}{
  keywordstyle=\bfseries,
}
\lstdefinestyle{base}{
  language=C++,
  basicstyle=\color{white},
  keywordstyle=\color{white},
  commentstyle=\sffamily\scriptsize\color{white},
  moredelim=**[is][\only<1->{\color{black}\lstset{style=highlight}}]{@1}{@},
  moredelim=**[is][\only<2->{\color{black}\lstset{style=highlight}}]{@2}{@},
  moredelim=**[is][\only<3->{\color{black}\lstset{style=highlight}}]{@3}{@},
  moredelim=**[is][\only<4->{\color{black}\lstset{style=highlight}}]{@4}{@},
  moredelim=**[is][\only<5->{\color{black}\lstset{style=highlight}}]{@5}{@},
  moredelim=**[is][\only<6->{\color{black}\lstset{style=highlight}}]{@6}{@},
  moredelim=**[is][\only<7->{\color{black}\lstset{style=highlight}}]{@7}{@},
  moredelim=**[is][\only<8->{\color{black}\lstset{style=highlight}}]{@8}{@},
  moredelim=**[is][\only<9->{\color{black}\lstset{style=highlight}}]{@9}{@},
  texcl=true,escapebegin=\hskip-6cm\color{red}
}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]%

  \foreach \o/\t in {%
    1-2/{General program structure},
    3/{Variables},
    4/{Reading numbers from standard input}
  }{
    \only<\o>{\expandafter\frametitle\expandafter{\t}}%
  }

\begin{lstlisting}[style=base,caption={C++ as C++ TexTests},label=cppascpptextests]
  @2int main() {@            // \only<1>{(1) How to construct main?}
    @4long a,b,c;@           // \only<3>{(3) How to declare variables?}
    @5scanf("%ld%ld",&a,&b);@// \only<4>{(3) How to read data?}
    @3return 0;@             // \only<2>{(2) How to exit correctly?}
  @3}@  
\end{lstlisting}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

**Remarks:**

I took the freedom to simplify your `\frametitle` specifications using a `\foreach` loop from the `pgffor` package. However, that is not the point here. The main idea is to have two different listing styles.

- Style `base` basically "hides" the listing by rendering all elements in white.
- Style `highlight` applies the real formatting.
- The trick is then to use the `moredelim` option of `lstlisting` to inject the style `highlight` only on given slides. Unfortunately it is not possible to pass an argument to `moredelim`, so I defined a series of delimiters `@1`, `@2` and so on.

For the "comments" I use another trick. The comments are always rendered in white (which is the reason you cannot see the comment delimiters `//`), but use the `texcl` option to automatically escape to LaTeX for the *content* of the comment. As we are in LaTeX land after the `//`, we can use `\only<>` to implement the overlay specifications. With `escapebegin` we give additional commands that are inserted by `lstlisting` before typesetting the comment contents. Here, I also use it to (kind of brutally) move the insertion position to the left, so that the comment appears close to the begin of the source line.

**Outcome:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello. Look great ! I believe it will save a lot of my lifetime :). One more thing : here we see "?" of whole lines, what about parts of line ? Is it possible to do sequence like: `int main( ??, ?? ){` -> `int main(int argc, ??){` -> `int main(int argc, char **argv}{`. If it would need complete rebuild of your solution, please leave it as it is -> short&sweet :). If it's just another "trick" to do and you have an idea, please share it :).

Comment: (P.S. I need a little bit of time to understand this, so I need time to decide whether is to "solution")

Comment: @GrzegorzWierzowiecki: Thats perfectly okay; you should also allow some time for other answers to show up – early acceptance of the only answer might demotivate other potential contributors and their solutions might be better. (I usually wait a week or so before accepting some answer).

Comment: I encountered problem with your solution. When sum of lengths of code line and comment is longer then width of slide, line gets broken and comment appears in next line, instead of the same. Any clue how to fix it ?

Comment: @GrzegorzWierzowiecki: Please update your question with a MWE that demonstrates this particular problem.